# getting "access denied" when installing viber in wine (and playonlinux)

Tags: debian, 32-bit, wine, viber

my setup:

thinkpad t420 (32-bit cpu)
debian 9
wine 1.8.7

i downloaded ViberSetup.exe, and i run:

wine ViberSetup.exe

(also tried it with playonlinux, exact same results)

once i accept the license on the install, i get "access denied". i have verified that i own the exe as well as the entire ~/.wine directory. i have looked at the log file, but i see nothing that i can discern (and "access denied" does not even appear in the file).

any ideas?

Comment: this question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: correct. does that mean i should not be posting it on stackoverflow?  if so, any suggestions?

Comment: you should go to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: i had searched there, but i will now ask the question there.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Wine [Access Denied]
Run the installer from the terminal, you won't have this problem:
Code:
cd /path/to/mounted/iso
wine setup.exe
Obviously, replace the path I typed with the correct one.

the thing which i had done when i am in same pb are

I burned the CD into an ISO imagefile.
Then i mounted the ISO file with the FuriusIso Mount.
After that, i opened a terminal and typed: gksudo nautilus (it will open a file browser with root access!).
Now find the mounted ISO path and edit the installer file's properties
Done!

Comment: as i said, i did run it from a terminal. i am not using a disk, wine is already installed, and i have downloaded the viber setup executable.

Comment: installing a wine program as root is explicitly not recommended. nor should it be.